# Setting a Default Color for All Angles and Right Angles in tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

This has been driving me crazy for months. Suppose I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B,0/5/C}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(B,A,C)
\tkzMarkAngle(C,B,A)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following image.

[image: MWE Right Triangle with black angles]

I want to make it so that all instances of `\tkzMarkRightAngle`, `\tkzMarkRightAngles`, `\tkzMarkAngle`, and , `\tkzMarkAngles` draw in magenta for their lines/arcs and not the default black. I can do this individually by using the option `\tkzMarkAngle[magenta]` or `\tkzMarkAngle[color = magenta]`. Doing such individually on each angle will produce what I want:

[image: MWE Right Triangle with magenta angles]

However, I want to set this globally. I know that I can do many other things globally, such as set up arc and line colors via

```
\tkzSetUpArc[color=magenta]
\tkzSetUpLine[color=magenta]
```

or that I can also change certain aspects of the right angle via

```
\tikzset{/tkzrightangle/size=0.5}
```

but I just cannot figure out how to set the color of all angles globally. Would anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could just define `\newcommand*\myMarkAngle[1][]{\tkzMarkAngle[{magenta,#1}]}` and use that instead. The `tkz` packages don't offer many helpful styles that can be used here.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think it was necessary to use a common style for all the angles. It seemed to me that this was not frequent enough because often the angles are filled with different colors but I will see if it is possible to modify the code slightly. This also leads to the colors of the arcs, marks ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Regarding defining a new command, that particular approach offered by @Qrrbrbirlbel is of course doable, but causes me to create 4 new commands. And, every time I need to update the color, I need to update all four of them. (Or make the solution longer and create a newcommand or variable for the color. So I was hoping to avoid it.

Regarding the infrequent usage, I don't know how often users choose just one color, but I was trying to mimic the textbooks I've used. In those books, all the angles are cyan, all the angles are magenta, or some combination thereof.

Comment: @JeffSlye Then do `\newcommand*\myMarkAngle[1][]{\tkzMarkAngle[{every mark angle,#1}]}` and `\pgfkeys{/tkzmkangle/every mark angle/.style=magenta}`. Then you only need to change the `every mark angle` instead of four commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two possibilities :

A)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B,0/5/C}
\begin{scope}[color=magenta]
   \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,A,C)
   \tkzMarkAngle(C,B,A)
\end{scope}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

B) I added in a previous version the possibility to use `pic`

```
 \tikzset{angle style/.style={color=magenta}} 
   
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B}
  \tkzDefTriangle[right,swap](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{C}
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](B,A)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above right](C)
  \tkzPicAngle["$\alpha$",draw=orange,
   <->,angle eccentricity=1.2,
   angle radius=1cm,angle style](B,A,C)
  \tkzPicRightAngle[draw,red,thick,
   angle eccentricity=.5,
   pic text=.,angle style](C,B,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Was hoping this wasn't the official answer, but thank you for the detailed response. I may go with the `pic` option, but I'll see which one goes better with my workflow! (Also totally didn't think of the scope option, as obvious as that sounds. Though I guess I didn't consider it since it isn't global for the entire document.)